# Find the values of the parameter $b$ and $p$ for which the series converges.

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I need to find the values of $b$ and $p$ for which the following sum converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sin^n\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)-\frac{b}{n^p}\right)$$
I believe it is best to use the Comparison Test or Limit Comparison Test, but I can't seem to find a working sequence to compare it to. Any idea?
$$$$
$\textbf{Addendum:}$ The tests that I have been exposed to, as of right now, are: Integral Test, Comparison Test, Limit Comparison Test, Absolute Convergence Test, Ratio Test, and Root Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sin^n\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)-\frac{b}{n^p}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin^n\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)-b\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\color{red}{p}} \\[4mm] \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin^n\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)\lt\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin^n\left(\frac32\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac32\right)}{1-\sin\left(\frac32\right)}
$$

Comment: For the first sum, can I just take any value  bigger than 1? Why did you specifically choose $\frac32$?

Comment: Nearest to $\,\frac{\pi}{2}\,$ and $\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1\,$.

Comment: Is it valid to state that the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sin\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)\right)^n$ is convergent since $\sin\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)<0\ \forall n>1$, as it can be looked as a geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n$ with $r=\sin\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)$?

Comment: @DMH16 Specifically, the direct comparison test was used.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $n\in\mathbb N$, we have a maximum:

$$\sin\left(1+\frac1n\right)<\sin\left(1+\frac12\right)<0.9975$$

We can thus conclude that if $\sum0.9975^n-\frac b{n^p}$, our sum converges as well.  By splitting the sum, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty0.9975^n<\infty$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac b{n^p}<\infty\ \forall\ p>1$$

Thus, it converges for all $b\in\mathbb R$ and $p>1$, or $b=0$ and all $p\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

If I have read the question correctly, then only the second term in the summation formula makes a difference since 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sin^n\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)\right)$$ converges using the root test. The second term ([Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)) converges for all $b$ and $p>1$, because $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{b}{t^p}$d$t$ is always smaller than the second part of the sum so its corresponds with the convergence of the summation. The integral converges for $p>1$.